# onclick even not working

Tags: javascript, php

in the code below on clicking the button corresponding price should be displayed and the click here text shud hide but it doesn't work nothing happens

```
<body>
<?php $itemprice  = array("$10","$3","$5","$7");?>
<?php $len = count($itemprice);
$i=0; 
?>

<div class= "gallery">
<?php while ($i<$len):?>
<div class="index">
<div class="clickbtn">
    <a id="hiddenprice-<?php echo $i; ?>" href="http://www.bookurl.com" onclick="show_price(<?php echo $i; ?>)" target="_blank">
   Click Here to reveal price <?php  echo $itemprice[$i]; ?>
    </a>
<a id="revealedprice-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;" href="http://www.bookurl.com"><?php  echo $itemprice[$i]; ?></a>
</div>

</div> 
<?php $i++;endwhile;
?>
<script>
   function show_price(<?php echo $i; ?>) {
       document.getElementById('revealedprice-<?php echo $i; ?>').style.display = '';
       document.getElementById('hiddenprice-<?php echo $i; ?>').style.display = 'none';
   }
</script>
</div>


</body>
```

u can see the outcome live at http://myproject.byethost7.com/test1.php

Comment: `function show_price(<?php echo $i; ?>)` is your problem.... you don't seem to understand the relationship between server side PHP used to generate the markup and client-side javascript, executable only after the markup has been renederd in a web browser.... change the whole of that script block to use javascript variables, not PHP variables

Comment: This isn't jquery code

Comment: Never seen such an array `array("$10","$3","$5","$7");`, you cannot use numbers only as variable names. Use `array(10, 3, 5, 7);` or `array($a, $b, $c, $d);`.

Comment: You are redirecting to a url on anchor tag as well as stating onclick event on it. on click the href is occuring by default not trigger onclick event

Comment: @danfromgermany the content is string in array and its getting pulled our correctly as u can see in the link

Comment: I could be wrong, but when you click on a link, the click event is fired, and only after that the redirection is done. Just think about some track tool, how would you detect a click if the event wasn't fired???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mess between the PHP code and javascript code.

Also, it's not clear what you're trying to do with that anchor. If you have a href defined, the user will navigate to that url, the onclick code is irrelevant in your case unless you cancel the navigation.

It seems to me that you want to do this. Take into account that you can't control 100% if the url will be opened on a new window or a new tab.

**HTML**

```
<a id="hiddenprice-<?php echo $i; ?>" href="#" onclick="show_price(<?php echo $i; ?>)">
    Click Here to reveal price <?php  echo $itemprice[$i]; ?>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
   function show_price(num) {
      document.getElementById('revealedprice-' + num).style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('hiddenprice-' + num).style.display = 'none';
      window.open("http://www.bookurl.com");
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

Notice `num` on `show_price`, the added `window.open` and the `return false` to cancel the default anchor behavior (navigate to the href)

Comment: @user3449454: please explain what you're trying to do. Having a href defined and your onclick activity are not compatible. You will navigate your page out.

Comment: on clciking the button i want to reveal the price also open a new tab with the link in href

Comment: so far I know, there is no realiable way to open a url in a new tab. If opening in a new browser window is enough, then you do have options. What it is sure is that your code won't do that :)

Comment: made the edits but nothing happens..see the link with the updated code

Comment: @user3449454: I had an extra `)` on my code, please copy the js part again.

Answer (score 1):

Do not trust everything you see :)

What would append if you use the previous answer, without understanding it? Try, but you're going to have a surprise.

Explanations.

```
<a id="hiddenprice-5" href="http://www.bookurl.com" onclick="show_price(5)" target="_blank">
Click Here to reveal price 52
</a>
```

Show_price function is now well defined. But. But you are using a link - the a tag -. When you're going to click, the effect would be fine, but there is still the redirection: the user would never see the revealed price.

In order to avoid this "kiss cool effect", you must use another tag than a, or add a return false; to your show_price function.

Comment: how do i get it to redirect as well as reveal the price

Comment: You really want both of them?

Comment: i added return false; to the script still not working

Comment: Add a jsfiddle, it would be easyer.

Comment: not redirect ...i want to open the link in new tab and reveal the price in the current one

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/14/ ...in jsfiddle for some reason only one btn is shown for same code

Comment: As long as I know, open a new tab with js would cause a focus lost. You can still try something using window.open, but I can't be sure of the result. Did you know that this is a very wrong practice to redirect the user outside your website? Keep it will keep it's money, and you must try to keep the user as long as possible, but, I say that, I say nothing..

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/5/ with static single data it worked ...but i can't get it to work with muliple datas